# Get property of interface after running http get service

Tags: json, angular, http, service

I can not use the property of the array that i get from my JSON file through the http get service. The purpose is to print out the Widget array to the web

**service.ts:**

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import "rxjs/Rx";
import {Interface} from './interface'

@Injectable()
export class Service {
 private url = " ";
 loadDashboard(): Observable<Interface[]>{
  return this.http.get(this.url)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    return <Interface>response.json();
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
 }

 private handleError(error: Response){
  return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
 }
}
```

**interface.ts:**

```
export interface Interface {
 layout: number;
 id: number;
 column: number;
 row: number;
}
```

When I set _array: Interface[], it returns undefined, and code get error at the function push: [ts] Property 'layout' does not exist on type 'Interface[]'. 
When I set just _array; the code is compiled, but nothing happen

**typescript.ts:**

```
export class Component implements OnInit { 
 _array: Interface[];
 Widget: Array<{id: number, col: number, row: number}> = [];

 constructor (private service: Service) { }

 getDashboard(){
  this.service.loadDashboard()
    .subscribe(
     loadArray => {this._array = loadArray}
     console.log(this._array); //this line return the data in the JSON file
    )
    console.log(this._array); //this line return undefined
    this.Widget.push({id: this._array.id, layout: this._array.layout, column: this._array.col, row: this._array.row})
 }

 ngOnInit(){
  getDashboard()
 }
}
```

**JSON.json:**

```
{
 {
  "id": 1,
  "layout": 1,
  "col": 1,
  "row": 1
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "layout": 1,
  "col": 1,
  "row": 2
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem by moving the subscribe to ngOnInit

**typescript.ts**

```
getDashboard() {
 this.service.loadDashboard().map(loadArray => {this._array = loadArray})
}
ngOnInit(){
 this.getDashboard().subscribe( _ => {
  this.Widget.push({id: this._array.id, layout: this._array.layout, column: this._array.col, row: this._array.row})
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
export class Component implements OnInit { 

 array: Interface[];
 Widget: Array<{id: number, col: number, row: number}> = [];

 constructor (private service: Service) { }

 getDashboard(){
  this.service.loadDashboard()
    .subscribe((loadArray) => {
        this.array = loadArray
        this.Widget.push({id: this.array.widgets.id, layout: this.array.widgets.layout, column: this.array.widgets.col, row: this.array.widgets.row});
  });

 }

 ngOnInit(){
  getDashboard()
 }
}
```

Move this.Widget.push inside the subscribe method.

Comment: take a look at the variable **array**. Um not using the **_array**

Comment: It still get the same error. I think that it's just a way to declare a property, it has nothing to do with the logic of code

Comment: Can you update the question with the output of console.log(this._array); ? And the json you have provided is **not an array.**

Comment: in the typescript.ts i have included it, the first line inside the subscribe return the json. The second line outside the subscribe return undefined

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of asynchronous behavior of subscription of observable. You should do all the operation inside subscribe method.

And also you should have array in response to access each object. So, change JSON response.

**JSON.json**

```
[
 {
  "id": 1,
  "layout": 1,
  "col": 1,
  "row": 1
 },
 {
  "id": 2,
  "layout": 1,
  "col": 1,
  "row": 2
 }
]
```

**typescript.ts:**

```
export class Component implements OnInit { 

    _array: Interface[];
    Widget: Array<{id: number, layout:number, column: number, row: number}> = [];

    constructor (private service: Service) { }

    getDashboard(){
      this.service.loadDashboard()
        .subscribe((loadArray) => {
            this._array = loadArray
            this._array.forEach( ele => {
                this.Widget.push({
                    id: ele.id,
                    layout: ele.layout, 
                    column: ele.col, 
                    row: ele.row
                });
            })

       });

    }

   ngOnInit(){
      getDashboard()
   }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using this.array.widgets.id? I don't see object named widgets in your JSON.json

Comment: sorry , it's my bad, that's from the old code, i have edited it

Comment: Try printing "loadArray" inside subscribe and see what you get

Comment: i can't find a place to console.log(this.loadArray) without getting errors

Comment: You can do it anywhere inside subscribe method... For now you can do it after "this._array = loadArray"

Comment: it has the same data as the   _array, which is the data of the json file

Comment: Okay, Problem is with your response data.. It should contain array to access all its objects. I have edited the answer. now it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**service.ts**

```
import { Http, Response, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import "rxjs/Rx";
import {Interface} from './interface'

@Injectable()
export class Service {
 private url = " ";
 loadDashboard(): Observable<Interface[]>{
  return this.http.get(this.url)
  .map((response: Response) => {
    return <Interface[]>response.json();    // CHAGNE Type here
  })
  .catch(this.handleError);
 }

 private handleError(error: Response){
  return Observable.throw(error.statusText);
 }
}
```

**typescript.ts**

```
export class Component implements OnInit { 
 _array: Interface[];
 Widget: Array<{id: number, col: number, row: number}> = [];

 constructor (private service: Service) { }

 getDashboard(){
  this.service.loadDashboard()
    .subscribe(loadArray => {
        this._array = loadArray;
        // Use foreach as it returns array of objects
        this._array.forEach(ele => {    
            this.Widget.push({id: ele.id, layout: ele.layout, column: ele.col, row: ele.row})
        });
     });

 }

 ngOnInit(){
  this.getDashboard()
 }
}
```

Comment: i tried forEach, and also for:

    for(let i  = 0 ; i < array.length; i++) {
     this.Widget.push({id: this.array[i].id, layout: this.array[i].layout, col: this.array[i].col, row: this.array[i]..row})
    }
But it doesn't print out anything

Comment: Did you change return type in service.ts

Comment: try after doing that change

    `return <Interface[]>response.json();    // CHAGNE Type here`